# Creating Custom dialog/pop up box HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html, modal-dialog

I am learning how to create custom dialog box in HTML by following tutorials but haven't been able to quite understand how I can create them the way i want. I want to achieve something like below:

The first one I want to create contains a listview.

[image]

The second one is dialog box that has textbox to enter in keyword and add to database by clicking create.

[image]

I have followed tutorials but being a beginner, I haven't be able to full understand how to go about create, therefore any help would be nice.

Through searching online, I have been able to create using modals to come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/jLs8myoa/9/

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Input Form</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
           enter keyword <input type="textbox" id="textbox1"> </input><br>
                <button type="button">Search</button>
                <div> Listview </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

Few tutorials i have followed

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_signup_form.asp

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RLE2Q7OzME

Comment: Hey, creating a custom dialog is easy. But you already have fiddle which contains the code to open/close a dialog. And you just need to change the UI of dialog to as per your requirement. Now in which part you facing problem? What exactly is it that you dont understand?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. One problem I am having is to create listview - I will be creating a database to populate that listview later on but I am not sure how I can create the listview to accommodate that. Another issue is the positioning of the elements within the modal (is modal best in this scenario?)

Answer (score 0):

In your code modal opens properly, I can't see any problem over there.
You just need to advance a bit in HTML, and CSS.

Start with W3 schools, they have awesome and easy tutorials for HTML5 and CSS. I think you will be able to make what you want once your basic will be clear. There are many ways to design the modal you are making.

Follow this...
[CSS Tutorials...](https://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Custom modal without Bootstrap...
[CSS modal...](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and the links i will go through them. One problem I am having is creating the listview. I will be having a database to populate the listview but I am not sure how to create the listview. The problem I am having is the positioning of the elements within the modal.

Comment: here, have a look...This little code may help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/Jayraj178/gLok63eh/2/